# SSRS Bar chart legend issues

Tags: reporting-services

I am getting wrong legend values when I create the following simple bar chart.

[image]

Currently I have the chart on the left showing a legend of "Avg age, Avg Height" and x axes as "city, coutry"

What I want is the chart on the right.  The Legend should be : "city, country" and the axes "Avg Age, Avg Height".

My issue here is to change label data to x axies data and x axies data to label.

I can get this chart with above data in Microsoft Excel very easily with the following steps

1. Insert bar chart
2. Select chart data as above table.
3. Interchange row / legends

Comment: Columns: Country  city   Avg Age Avg Height
Data:        Usa    NewYork   80 6
Data:        Usa     Dallas           85  5.9
Data:        Canada Vancover   90 6.6  Bar chart with x axes as country, city  , Y axies Ave age, ave height,

Comment: Is it possible to re-phrase this question to make the desired outcome and current state clearer.  I appreciate you cannot upload pictures yet, but could you include links to images hosted elsewhere instead?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/cjo6fw9qx/  is the chart I am trying to prepare

Comment: Is it important that the two groups appear oin teh same chart?  Is it possible to change the underlying SQL at all?

Comment: Can you sugguest How sql can be changed?. I tried to convert to matrix rather than list of results like above no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

By converting above table to the following Value giving chart on right side.
Country city    Series  Value

- USA NewYork  Avg Age 80
- USA  Dallas  Avg Age 85
- Canada   Vancover    Avg Age 90
- USA  NewYork Avg Height  6
- USA  Dallas  Avg Height  5.9
- Canada   Vancover    Avg Height  6.6

Thanks,